# GitLab не запускается runner

Tags: gitlab, непрерывная-интеграция, gitlab-runner

Установил runner для windows и зарегистрировал его. Но при пуше ни чего не происходит.

C:\GitLab-Runner>gitlab-runner.exe status

Runtime platform arch=386 os=windows pid=14740 revision=6214287e version=13.1.0
gitlab-runner: Service is running!

В gitlab зарегистрирован.

[image: gitlab runner]

файл yml.

```
stages:
  - build

build_job:
  stage: build
  only:
    - master

  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run build

  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 week
    paths:
      - dist/
```

Дефолтные runners запускаются, а мой нет.
[image: default pipe]

Comment: Последний скрин это что? Как файл yaml называется? Что на странице пайпланов проекта?

Comment: @AlexR. Последний скрин это и есть страница с паплайнами. Тот runner который сейчас активный у меня тут не отображен.
yml называется - .gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: Что-то тут не сходится. На скрине три стейджа, в файле один. У можно указать теги. Это теги указать в yaml, определив требуемый раннер.

Comment: Извините может я не верно описываю ситуацию.
На скрине паплайн от предыдущего runner , как я его подключил (Settings -> CI/CD -> Auto DevOps(поставил чекбокс Default to Auto DevOps pipeline)). 
Я же сейчас создал, зарегистрировал и подключил (первый скрин) свой runner, так вот его в паплайнах нет.